# Export Search Crawl errors for a particular content source?

Tags: search, export

We have a setup where SharePoint 2010 crawls several file share locations. After the crawls, we have ended up with thousands of errors. What I want to do is to export all these errors preferably to Excel instead of having to page through hundreds of pages on Central Admin.

I specifically want to export error messages for a particular content source. Is there an easy way to achieve this with PowerShell?

Edit:

I used a PowerShell script that exports *all* error messages as follows, but I can't figure out how to export only error messages pertaining to just one Content Source amongst all the different content sources in my Search Application:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Where-Object 
{$_.Name -eq "Search Service Application"}

$logViewer = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Logviewer $ssa
$ErrorList = $logViewer.GetAllStatusMessages() | Select ErrorId

Foreach ($errorId in $ErrorList)
{
  If ($errorId.errorId -eq 0 -or $errorId.errorId -eq 1)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    $crawlLogFilters = New-Object 
                       Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLogFilters
                       $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter(“MessageId”, $errorId.errorId)
                       "Processing Error Code : " + $errorId.errorId
   $startNum = 0

   $errorItems += $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData
                             ($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $startNum))
    Write-Host "Processing $startNum"
    WHILE($startNum -ne -1)
     {
           $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter(“StartAt”, $startNum);$startNum = 0;$errorItems += 
           $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $startNum));Write-Host  
            "Processing $startNum";
     }
  }
}

$errorItems | Export-CSV crawllog.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The script below is based on [Microsoft blog team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2011/06/22/exporting-sharepoint-2010-search-crawl-logs.aspx)  which sets an example on how to export the Crawl Logs

```
#============================================================================ 
#Powershell script to pull all the crawl logs and display based on errorId 
#============================================================================ [IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Convert-Path (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem)))
#Replace "Search Service Application" in the script with the exact name of the SSA that you browse to for viewing the crawl log. 
#With FAST you have multiple Search SSA’s and hence specify the name of the SSA that you use to view the crawl log data. 
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "UoN FAST Search Connector Service Application"} 
#This should list only one SSA object. 
$ssa 
#Create a LogViewer object associated with that SSA 
$logViewer = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Logviewer $ssa 
#Get a List of all errors/warnings in the Crawl Log
$ErrorList = $logViewer.GetAllStatusMessages() | Select ErrorId 
#Loop through each type of error and pull that data $currentUser = [Environment]::UserDomainName + "\" + [Environment]::UserName;
$machine = [Environment]::MachineName;
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyyMMdd');
$logFile = "$date-installationlog.txt";
if ($logfile -eq $null)
{
  $logFile = New-Item -type file "$date-installationlog.txt"; 
}
Foreach ($errorId in $ErrorList) 
{ 
    $crawlLogFilters = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLogFilters 
    #Filter based on the Error Id 
    $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("MessageId", $errorId.errorId)        
    "Pulling data for Message ID : " + $errorId.errorId 
    $nextStart = 0 
    $urls = $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $nextStart)) 
    #Data from the crawl log will be available in the DataTable $urls. If this number is larger than the number of records requested (50 by default), then use only 50 records, ignore the rest. 
    WHILE($nextStart -ne -1)
 {
  $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("StartAt", $nextStart);
  $nextStart = 0;
  $urls = $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $nextStart));

  for ($i=0; $i -le $urls.Rows.Count -1 ; $i++)
  {
   # Just output the URL, the Error (if any) and the Error Code.
   [System.String]::Format('{0},{1}, {2}',$urls.Rows[$i].DisplayUrl, $urls.Rows[$i].ErrorMsg, $urls.Rows[$i].ErrorLevel) | Out-File $logFile -append;
  } 
 } 
}
```

If you're looking for specific content amongst the crawl logs, not just errors, you can just export to a text file and then use Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ as a search tool which has a fantastic search capability.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Logviewer class is obsolete in the newer version,  anybody knows what is equivalent to this class now?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try (uncomment the lines that you want to use)

```
    $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Search Service Application"}
$ssaContent = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content($ssa)

$logViewer = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Logviewer $ssa
$ErrorList = $logViewer.GetAllStatusMessages() | Select ErrorId

Foreach ($errorId in $ErrorList)
{
    if ($errorId.errorId -eq 0 -or $errorId.errorId -eq 1 -or $errorId.errorId -eq 2 -or $errorId.errorId -eq 745)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $crawlLogFilters = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLogFilters;
        $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("MessageId", $errorId.errorId);
        #$crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("Url", "Contains", "\\officeshare\user");
        #$crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("ContentSourceId", 86);
        "Processing Error Code: " + $errorId.errorId;
        $startNum = 0;
        $errorItems += $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $startNum));
        Write-Host "Processing $startNum";
        WHILE($startNum -ne -1)
        {
            $crawlLogFilters.AddFilter("StartAt", $startNum);
            $startNum = 0;
            $errorItems += $logViewer.GetCurrentCrawlLogData($crawlLogFilters, ([ref] $startNum));
            Write-Host "Processing $startNum";
        }
    }
}
$errorItems | Export-CSV crawllog.csv
```